# Searching and Sorting Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

`void sort(int[] arr){
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
            if(arr[j] < arr[i]){
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}`

I just want to know what type of sorting algorithm is it, I know about Insertion sort, bubble sort and selection sort, but it appears to be none of those, I am a bit confused can someone help me out.

Comment: How does that not look like a selection sort?

Comment: Sahil, welcome to Stackoverflow. I hope you find it useful. To maximize the benefit you can potentially get from this site, please check out this page (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what on what types of questions are best asked and how to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) in ascending order. It's not a very good implementation because the inner loop performs a swap every time it finds a new smallest value. It could be improved by keeping an index of the smallest value and then doing a single swap after the inner loop.

Comment: Exactly. Although one could make the argument that optimizing a selection sort is akin to getting a $.01 per hour increase in pay. That extra 40 cents per week isn't going to make a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a BubbleSort. The algorithm works by swapping items in the list repeatedly until the list is sorted. This particular algorithm will sort the integers from greatest to least. BubbleSort has an average complexity of O(n^2) where n is the number of items in the list.

Comment: Bubble sort typically compares _adjacent_ elements, that's not what this code does. This code also sorts the values from least to greatest.

Comment: No, that is not a bubble sort. It's a selection sort.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example of the **Selection Sort**.

Selection sort is one of the O(n2) sorting algorithms, which makes it quite inefficient for sorting large data volumes. The idea of algorithm is quite simple. Array is imaginary divided into two parts - **sorted one and unsorted one**. At the beginning, sorted part is empty, while unsorted one contains whole array. At every step, algorithm finds minimal element in the unsorted part and adds it to the end of the sorted one. When unsorted part becomes empty, algorithm stops.

**Time Complexity**: O(n*n) as there are two nested loops.

**Auxiliary Space**: O(1)